# Compare a date in rails Active Record and PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to return records for the day before yesterday.  My records have date created_at column with date and time.  Whereas my condition has just the date so it always returns no records.

I had it working in dev on on sqlite using strftime to remove the time but how to I do it please on PG in live?

```
@articles = Article.where("created_at = ?", Date.yesterday-(params[:increment].to_i)).reverse
```

(increment = the number of days before yesterday.)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways. While I prefer a date range like:

```
.where("created_at > ? AND created_at < ?", date_from, date_to)
```

you can also use PostgreSQL built-in `date_trunc` function

```
.where("date_trunc('day', created_at) = ?", date)
```

But keep in mind, that you need postgres on your local dev machine too.

Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 3):

In current versions of Rails (since version 5.1) you can use the [`all_day` helper](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/04/24/rails-5-1-has-introduced-date-all_day-helper.html) for queries like that:

```
date = (params[:increment].to_i + 1).days.ago
Article.where(created_at: date.all_day).reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

say today is

```
> DateTime.now
 => Mon, 26 Jun 2017 00:17:12 +0545
```

---

```
> Account.where('created_at between ? and ?', 2.days.ago.beginning_of_day, 2.days.ago.end_of_day)
  Account Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE (created_at between '2017-06-23 00:00:00' and '2017-06-23 23:59:59.999999') LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]


 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Asset id: 3, name: "created 4 days ago", code: nil, type: "Asset", created_at: "2017-06-17 06:57:13", updated_at: "2017-06-21 06:57:13">]>
```

- In this way, you will find articles created from the start of `Jun 25 00:00:00` to `Jun 26 00:00:00`.

See about [beginning_of_day](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-beginning_of_day) and [end_of_day](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-end_of_day)